# Exception to haloform reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, halogenation

While explaining haloform reaction my teacher told me that Me3C-(C=O)-CH3 does not give haloform reaction.
What is the reason behind it since it does have a CH3 group?

Comment: The carbon in "MeC" looks like it has only two bonds. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you mean Me3C-(C=O)-CH3 ?

Comment: @Adiboy sorry for the error, yes what you said is the one i am asking for

Comment: I suggest that you read this well-written answer, especially the second paragraph https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/111543/94220

Comment: Pinacolone is the common name of Me3C-(C=O)-CH3